# cronjob dos screen display

Tags: php, cron, windows-server-2008, dos

I am running a cron job for php using task scheduler on windows server 2008

I have set the task to run every 5 minutes.

Now I get a blank dos screen every 5 minutes when the task runs on the server.

Is there any way that the DOS window does not show up every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the task scheduler to run your command using this:

```
start /b cmd /c call [your command here]
```

The `/b` is for background.

The `/c` is for close when done.